# Jump without bouncing in physics engine

Tags: 3d, physics, ogre, bullet-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am using Ogre3D as my rendering API, and OgreBullet as my physics engine.

I have an test entity that when the y part of the velocity is 0 and spacebar is pressed, the velocity changes to, lets say: (10, 10, 0) that is a forward jump.

The thing is that when it arrives to the ground, instead of staying still (like any normal human jump) it bounces like a box and changes orientation.

What would be the correct way of implementing a human-like jump in 3D? I fixed it using a `if()` in the update loop that sets the y-velocity to 0 if it touches the ground, but this doesn't seem the correct way of doing it.

Comment: You might want to look at bullet Kinematic Character Controllers, which model human character physics better than a simple rigid body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setting the y-velocity isn't the correct way of doing things. You need to set the restitution of the object by passing the correct value (0 = no bounce) into the btRigidBodyConstructionInfo which is passed into the rigid body.

Comment: I set it to 0 and it still bounces a little

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XQEaSeFr

Comment: Have you ensure the colliding floor has a value of 0 as well?

Comment: Yes. Full code here: http://pastebin.com/CnTgUfMD friction is 1 though, although I think that shouldn't affect it too much. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: When I change the restitution to a higher value (`0.5f`, for example), the bounce is way larger. When it is 0 it is small, but it still bounces a little. I just want no bounce at all, which is my main problem

Comment: @Pacha It seems the collider adds some, I'd try a smaller value such as 0.01 and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but what is the collider?

Comment: I followed this answer: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/how-do-you-stop-ogrebullet-capsule-from-falling-over And it doesn't rotate (yay!), but it has some bug in its velocity that lags a bit when I try to change the position or jump again.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere on the Bullet forums that a certain amount of bounce velocity is nearly always added to deal with overlapping (I'll find the source if I can but for now you might have to take my word for it). I think the only way to avoid this is indeed to set the y velocity to 0, or set it to the same as the whatever your object lands on (if you are jumping on moving objects). This might also mean you need to resolve overlapping yourself, however, by moving the object upwards a certain amount.

Comment: I used a ghost object and a character controller interface